# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { with Jest and Babel

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am using ES6 modules with Babel 7+. In one function, I am doing something like this:

```
// some function I want to test

function something() {
...
  require('path/to/some/file.js');
...
}
```

That `path/to/some/file.js` file uses `import` statements like this

```
// path/to/some/file.js

import { Something } from 'package';
```

When I try to run the test with Jest,it complains like this:

```
import { Something } from 'package';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

This is the configuration I am using inside `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

And this is the configuration from `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]],
};
```

These are my dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
  }
```

Is there something I can do to fix this?